# How can I return the names from this multi dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to take the names from this multi dimensional array and return them, but I am unsure how to do it.

```
self.accounts= {
            'Alice': {'balance': 100, 'history': []},
            'Bob': {'balance': 200, 'history': []}, 
            'Charlie': {'balance': 300, 'history': []}, 
            'Dave': {'balance': 400, 'history': []}, 
            'Eve': {'balance': 500, 'history': []}, 
            'Frank': {'balance': 600, 'history': []}, 
            'Grace': {'balance': 700, 'history': []}, 
            'Heidi': {'balance': 800, 'history': []}, 
            'Ivan': {'balance': 900, 'history': []}, 
            'John': {'balance': 1000, 'history': []}, 
            'Kate': {'balance': 1100, 'history': []},
        }
```

I tried using `return self.accounts[:,0]` to return the first column of the array since that includes the names, but I got `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use `self.accounts.keys()` which returns a dict_keys

And if you prefer to obtain a list, you can cast using

`list(self.accounts.keys())`

Comment: Or just `list(self.accounts)`

Comment: yes, casting the dict to list does work, but I think it makes it less readable and wouldn't recommend it to a beginner